# I need help with creating CAML

Tags: caml-query

I have a document library MyLib and i need to find specified file in it .

```
        query.Query = @"
              <Where>
                 <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name='Title' />
                        <Value Type=" + name + 
                         @">as</Value>
                 </Eq>
              </Where>
         ";
```

how can I specify  my Document Library?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const string camlQuery = @"<query><where><and><gt><fieldref name="Price"><value type="Number">1000</value></fieldref></gt><leq><fieldref name="Price"><value type="Number">10000</value></fieldref></leq></and></where><orderby><fieldref ascending="False" name="Price"></fieldref></orderby></query>";    
try
            {
                using (SPSite objSite = new SPSite("sitename"))
                {
                    using (SPWeb objWeb = objSite.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        // Building a query
                        SPQuery query=new SPQuery();
                        query.Query=camlQuery;

                        // Retrieving the data from the List
                        SPList objList=objWeb.Lists["Product List"];
                        SPListItemCollection items= objList.GetItems(query);

                        // Prinitng the header
                        Console.WriteLine("{0,-25} {1,-20} {2,-15} {3}", "Title", "Price", "Qunatity", "Is Available");

                        foreach (SPListItem objListItem in items)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("{0,-25} {1,-20} {2,-25} {3}", objListItem["Title"], objListItem["Price"],
                                                                             objListItem["Quantity"], objListItem["Is Available"]);
                        }

                    }
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error Occured:", ex.Message);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: thank you, and query will be like i mentioned above?          query.Query = @"
              <Where>
                 <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name='Title' />
                        <Value Type='Text'> "+ name + 
                         @"</Value>
                 </Eq>
              </Where>
         ";

Comment: it should be like this i think u missed the <query> tag-- query.Query = @" <query><Where> <Eq> <FieldRef Name='Title' /> <Value Type='Text'> "+ name + @"</Value> </Eq> </Where></query>";  let me know if it not helps u

Comment: You should NOT include the `<Query>` tag when assigning to SPQuery.Query

Comment: I so much appreciated !

Comment: Thanks Lena now i got 46 reputation i am new to share point i have only 2 days experiance your comments giving me some push up